# vscode find all references not working for functions

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a large C project spanning hundreds of files. Find all references works occasionally but not always for variables (it may fail to find anything for something it found 5 minutes ago, though if I search via search history it will find references again), and never for functions. This is a recent development as it was working 2 days ago. Go to definition and go to declaration do work normally for everything.

I'm currently on 1.76.2 though I also tried on 1.81, having uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times. Restarted the computer ofc. Uninstalled and reinstalled all my extensions (C/C++, C/C++ Extension Pack, C/C++ Themes, CMake, CMake Tools).